# chrome notification list type notification won't display primary message

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I don't know why the primary message in chrome notifications of `type:"list"` won't get displayed.

According to the [official documents](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/richNotifications#list), `message` is still required in the options we send to create the notifications but it doesn't show the message in the notification. I have my options object here-

```
 options={
  type: "list",
  title: "Test",
  message: "This message doesn't get displayed",
  iconUrl: "icon128.png", 
  items: [{ title: "But", message: "This gets displayed."},
          { title: "And", message: "This gets displayed."},
          { title: "And This", message: "Also gets displayed."}]
};
```

Am I missing something? Is there a workaround? I didn't share the manifest because the notification is working fine if I change `type:"list"` to `type:"basic"` and replace `items` with a `contextMessage`. I just want to display the message *and* the list.